# how to add curl syntax for facebook re-scrape url

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am new in web development sector. It's seem to impossible to fetch my web pages using facebook Open Graph Object Debugger manually. When I search code to force re-scrape I found this code, but confused where to add. I thought it is php function and include , but it print parse error. Is it complete code ?, am I right ? Many website and blog advice to use following code. But I have no idea. I can't find clear way.

```
<?php   $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
<?php curl "http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=$url"; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I'm using

```
   private function updateFacebookScrape($url){
        $ch = curl_init("http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=".$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Also, make sure curl is installed on the server.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your response, I create php.ini file in public_html folder. I include code extension=php_curl.dll in this file. Then edit my page using your code but it display error. : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected private (T_PRIVATE) in /home/..  What's wrong ?

Comment: You aren't using it in a class so get rid of 'private'